# How to specify column widths in RMarkdown to Word?

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown, pandoc

I've been struggling with this for a while and I was hoping someone might be able to help me out.  I'm using Rmarkdown and Knitr in RStudio to produce a word document (.docx), which I am populating with data.  The only issue is no matter what I do, I can't seem to create consistent column widths.  I've tried using a reference .docx, with no luck, and I've tried using pandoc.table with "split.cells", which changes the result printed to R console, but the formatting goes away when Knitr puts it into word:

```
panderOptions("table.split.cells",c(10,1,10,1,1))
pandoc.table(function_to_create_table(x))
```

Any suggestions? I feel like there's an obvious answer that's been eluding me.

Comment: just to be clear, you mean table column widths vs actual page columns, correct?

Comment: This feature is not supported for `docx` in `pandoc` (yet?), see this related thread: https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/515

Comment: @hrbrmstr, yes, I mean table width, sorry I should have specified.

daroczig, it looks like it works for .odt then, am I reading that right?

Comment: Aye, though it may just be "better" vs exactly what you want. If you really need to target `docx` and need more precision [ReporteRs](https://github.com/davidgohel/ReporteRs) may be the way to go.